# subprocess.check_output is too slow on script python but not in interactive python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess, debian

My question is about subprocess.

I'm using subprocess to call an external program, I've used the check_output() method in which I pass args as list. what I've noticed is that when using check_output() from the interactive shell it takes 3 minutes (which is the correct time for executing the external program in my case [there is no problem if the process stays blocked waiting the response]) however when I'm using the same method with the same params in a python script it can take up to 1hour !.

Is there anyone who faced this situation before? any suggestion ?

For information I'm using Python3.7.3 on a Debian 10.

Thanks is advance

---- edit:

I've nothing special in my code

My script is  just:

```
from subprocess import check_output
try:
    #commandList is the programm (external bin) I would excute with its params
    result = check_output(commandList) 
    print(result.decode("latin-1"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Are you doing any other work in the Python script? Try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @IonutTicus check my edit :) it's just a simple check_output there is nothing special with it

Comment: What happens if you run it with `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`?

Comment: thanks @SpiderPig1297 I've fixed the issue bu using subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True) and Communicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess. STDOUT, shell=True)`  fixed the problem.

Comment: It was hard to find this solution, but it's work perfectly.